# How do you classify groups when the inputs are paired?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

My data is like this: there is a choice between two alternatives and the customer chooses one. Each time the alternatives are different. I would like to characterize a desirable alternative. I don't want to use a normal classification algorithm because I don't want to lose the information that one alternative was chosen over the other in the pair. Does anyone have suggestions for ways to do this, or types of algorithms for solving this problem? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is called [two-alternative forced choice (2AFC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-alternative_forced_choice) task, a common technique in Psychology research. The [Diffusion Decision Model (DDM)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2474742/) is used to analyze the data.